# XML parsing error rendering special characters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

When I render xml with special characters in it

```
render xml: result
```

I get the following error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 3 at column 7: error parsing attribute name
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

here's the xml I'm trying to render. I get that it's the parentheses that's hosing me up. Is there a way I can just encode the entire xml in one swoop?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locales>
  <NY-(DOWNSTATE)>
    <name>NY (DOWNSTATE)</name>
    <state>NY</state>
    <bcbs-host-id nil="true"/>
  </NY-(DOWNSTATE)>
  <NY-(QUEENS)>
    <name>NY (QUEENS)</name>
    <state>NY</state>
    <bcbs-host-id nil="true"/>
  </NY-(QUEENS)>
  <NY-(UPSTATE)>
    <name>NY (UPSTATE)</name>
    <state>NY</state>
    <bcbs-host-id nil="true"/>
  </NY-(UPSTATE)>
</locales>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that XML support tag with special characters.

Comment: May we can declare ```<MY_DOWNSTATE> </MY_DOWNSTATE>``` and something like that

Comment: @HirenBhalani yes I can change those tags, but is there a way to programmatically do that? Strip out all special characters from tags?

Comment: If you are having this whole XML in single variable then you can try this `.gsub("-(", "+").gsub(")", "")` .